# Algorithm similar to 'Fizzbuzz'

Tags: python

I have a function

```
def process_list(mylist):
    return [x for x in mylist if isinstance(x, int)];
```

I need to modify this function so that in the new list that is returned, every integer divisible by 3 is replaced by -1, every integer divisible by 5 is replaced by -2, and every integer divisible by both is replaced by -3. Other integers are left unchanged. As before non-integers should be dropped.

Thus, `process_list([1, 3, 5, 15, 22, 'b'])` should return `[1, -1, -2, -3, 22].`

I can do this by using if-else. But I want to know the pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: Using `if/else` probably is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the function like this.

```
def process_list(mylist):
    return [(-3 if x % 15 == 0 else (-2 if x % 5 == 0 else ( -1 if x % 3 == 0 else x))) for x in mylist if isinstance(x, int)]
```

Comment: Craming everything and the kitchen sink into a barely readable one-liner is about as unpythonic as possible.

Comment: A good example of *just because you can, doesn't mean you should*. I would not be happy to run in to the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, pythonic for me is not a synonym for one-liner.
See [this](http://artifex.org/~hblanks/talks/2011/pep20_by_example.html).

Because `flat is better than nested` and `sparse is better than dense`

```
def process_list(mylist):
    # filter, prefer generator expression
    tmp = (x for x in mylist if isinstance(x, int))

    # mapping logic
    mappings = ((15, -3), (5, -2), (3, -1))
    def fizzbuzz(num):
        try:
            return next(v for k, v in mappings if num%k == 0)
        except StopIteration:
            return num 
    # return a mapped list
    return map(fizzbuzz, tmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the pythonic way *is* to use if-else in this case.

For example

```
def process_list(mylist):
    return list_filter(x) for x in mylist if isinstance(x, int)]

def list_filter(x):
    if x % 3 == 0:
         return -1
    elif ... # <snip>
```

(even though I'd probably rewrite the `process_list` function as a for loop that builds a new list)

Using list comprehension will most likely just be a lot *harder to read*, and/or *require multiple passes*.

Comment: filter is reserved word, is not it?

Comment: Agree on your opinion on list comprehension. BTW, overriding builtin function `filter` is not a good idea though...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say that this is the best way, but as someone that is not fond of long *if .. else* chains, I would rewrite Hannes Ovrén's *filter* as

```
def convert_ints(x, dividers=(15, 5 ,3)):
    for val, div in enumerate(dividers):
        if (x%div)==0:
            return -len(dividers)+val
    return x
```

This is scalbale solution, that may be easily expanded
**EDIT:**
for more complicated cases, a tuple of *lamdba*-s may be used:

```
conditions=(lambda x:x%15==0, lambda x:x%5==0, lambda x:x%3==0)
```